# How to avoid clickjacking my silverlight project?

Tags: .net, silverlight, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have a ASP / Silverlight application. I dont want it to be loaded in any iframe. (Avoid Clickjacking) I googled around and found that x-frame-options need to be set to SAMEORIGIN or DENY to avoid any such activity. As I am new to web development, I am confused where to add this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Web.config file. Set the following

```
<system.webServer> 
      ... 
      <httpProtocol> 
         <customHeaders> 
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
         </customHeaders> 
      </httpProtocol> 
      ... 
</system.webServer>
```

The detail explanation is given [here](http://technowide.net/2014/12/08/clickjacking-protect-youself-hack/)